# Check if string is valid html tag.

Tags: javascript

Is there any Native Javascript Functions to check if html tag exists?

I mean :

```
 var tag = "div";
 alert(isValidTag(tag)) // true;
 alert(isValidTag("foo")) // false;
```

*If there is no native function for that, I will keep my function :*

```
function isValidTag(tagName) {
  var tags = ["div","span","a","link" ... "body"];
  for(var i=0, len = tags.length; i++ < len; ) {
    if(tags[i] == tagName) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If you care about performance, you'd be better off making the "tags" variable be an object initialized outside that function, and with the tag names being keys.  Then you would not have to iterate through the array to make the determination of whether a string is or is not a tag.

Comment: @Pointy +1. Move the `var tags` outside of the `isValidTag` scope so you are not declaring it every time you can `isValidTag`

Comment: Instead of iterating, you can check (indexOf > -1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
tags = 'a b body...'.split(' ');
function isTag(tag) {
  return tags.indexOf(tag.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No. JS has nothing HTML specific in it at all, and DOM doesn't add anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be as efficient, I haven't done any time trials on it, but it can still be a good alternative to having to maintain a list of all the possible values yourself.

```
var isHTML = (function() {
  var unknown = '[object HTMLUnknownElement]', overrides = {CANVAS:1,VIDEO:1}; //html5 elements. Some browsers don't support these.
  return function(tag) {
    return overrides[tag = tag.toUpperCase()] || (!overrides.hasOwnProperty(tag) && (overrides[tag] = (document.createElement(tag).toString() !== unknown)));
  };
})();
```

This method will first check for a cached result, and if there isn't one it will determine a result based on the browser's own `document.createElement`. If the browser doesn't support it then we can safely assume it isn't an html tag.

Some sample outputs:

```
isHTML('curve'); //false
isHTML('div'); //true
isHTML('DIV'); //true
isHTML('tbody'); //true
isHTML('object'); //true
isHTML('document'); //false
isHTML('html'); //true
isHTML('svg'); //false
isHTML('rect'); //false
```

Comment: Neat solution, but can you explain this: isHTML('my-custom-element') = true, isHTML('mycustomelement') = false

Comment: Looks like some obscure behaviour of document.createElement.

Comment: *bloop* 'my-custom-element' still counts as a valid html tag. According to this ( http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/ ) browsers allow you to register custom elements requiring a dash to distinguish from regular ones.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Sollace

Answer (score 3):

```
var tags = {a: true, b: true, /*...,*/ body: true};

function isTag(_tag)
{
  return tags[_tag];
}
```

Thank you, @rsp, for suggesting this simplification

Comment: Instead of: `var tags = new Array; tags["a"] = true; tags["b"] = true; ...` it can be written simpler as: `var tags = {a: true, b: true, ... };` and the same `isTag()` function will work without modifications.

Comment: This code is misleading. JavaScript has no associative arrays. `tags.length` will return `0`. What you're doing is assigning named properties to the `tags` **object**. You should make that clear by declaring it as such: `var tags = {}`.

Comment: Don't use arrays to store arbitrary string keys.